# How to select the set of check box value using jquery Dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a list of set check box with sub check box . Please review the attached image!

```
[] Gender
    [] Male
    [] Female
    [] Baby

[] Weight 
    [] 50kg
    [] 100kg
    [] 75kg     

[] Color
    [] Brown
    [] Block
    [] White
```

What i need , If we select Gender (Parent check box )then the sub check boxes(Male, Female,Baby) also will be checked, If we uncheck the gender check box also the sub check box also uncheck.

My code for check box is below

```
 {foreach from= $product_param item=key}
                    <div class="parameters"> 
                        <span class="title"><input type="checkbox" name="product_param[]"  value="{$key->id}" id="product_param_selectall" />&nbsp;&nbsp;{$key->param_name}</span> 
                        {foreach from= $key->child_name item=keys}
                        <span><input type="checkbox" name="product_param_child[]"  value="{$key->id}" id="product_param" class="child_param-{$key->id}"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;{$keys->param_name}</span> 
                        {/foreach}
                    </div>
                {/foreach}
```

Note : The values are dynamic values and id. [] - represent checkbox here

Comment: please share the html

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".title").on("click",":checkbox",function(){
if($(this).is(":checked"))
{
$(this).closest(".parameters").find("input[name='product_param_child']").attr("checked","checked");
}else{
$(this).closest(".parameters").find("input[name='product_param_child']").removeAttr("checked");

}

});
```

reference **[:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/)**

**[:checkbox](http://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/)**

**[attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)**

**[removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)**

Comment: wow..Great..It's 100 % worked for me .. Thanks for your valuable time :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution. Assuming HTML:

```
<div>
    <input class="parentCheckBox" type="checkbox">Gender</input><br />
    <input class="childCheckBox" type="checkbox">Male</input><br />
    <input class="childCheckBox" type="checkbox">Female</input><br />
</div>
<div>
    <input class="parentCheckBox" type="checkbox">Weight</input><br />
    <input class="childCheckBox" type="checkbox">50kg</input><br />
    <input class="childCheckBox" type="checkbox">100kg</input><br />
</div>
```

This would work:

```
$(function() {
    $('.parentCheckBox').click(function() {
        var parentDiv = $(this).parent();
        var isChecked = $(this).prop('checked');
        $('.childCheckBox', parentDiv).prop('checked', isChecked);
    });
});
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YeR3q/).

Comment: Thanks for your interest :)Andrew :)